# Customize SMS View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, messageui

I used [this tutorial on iPhone Developer Tips](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html) to send an SMS from an app. The methodin the tutorial works.

However, is there a way to customize the colors and fonts in the toolbar? The framework I am using is [`MessageUI`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MFMessageComposeViewController is a UINavigationController. You can do anything to it that you would to any other UINavigationController. You can ask for it's navigationBar and set the tintColor. You can also change the navigationItem of the viewController too.